# Create an inclinometer Android

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

I'm trying to replicate the behaviour of the [Clinometer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.plaincode.clinometer) app but without luck. What I'm looking for is pure inclination (sideways tilt, see image) independent of the backwards and forward tilt. The said Clinometer does excactly that.

[Image of phone orientations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyg7k.png)

So far I have this code to get azimuth, pitch and roll. Pitch is almost what I want, it behave as it should while the display's normal is pointing horizontally and is tilted sideways (see the top row of images). It also behave as it should when it's lying on its long end (middle image first row) and is tilted forward and backwards (keeps at 0). But when I have it on a short end and tilt it slightly forwards or backwards (see the second row of images) the pitch is going down. I want it to keep being 90/-90 degrees unless I tilt it sideways.

Any suggestions/ideas of how to accomplish that?

```
private float[] gravity = new float[3];
private float[] geomag = new float[3];
private float[] orientVals = new float[3];

private float[] rotationMatrix = new float[16];
private float[] inclinationMatrix = new float[16];

switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
      case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
           gravity = event.values.clone();
           break;
      case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
           geomag = event.values.clone();
           break;
}

if (gravity != null && geomag != null) {

     boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix,
                        inclinationMatrix, gravity, geomag);

     if (success) {
        SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, orientVals);

        azimuth = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientVals[0]);
        pitch = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientVals[1]);
        roll = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientVals[2]);

        inclineLabel.setText(String.format("%.0f ", pitch));
    }
}
```